# We have to prove that $H=${$(x_1,...,x_n)\in{\mathbb{R^n}}|a_1x_1+...+a_nx_n=0$} is an hyperplane of $\mathbb{R^n}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, dimension-theory-algebra

I've got $\space$ $V$  $K$ - vectorial space, and $H$ which is a subspace of $V$. We say that $H$ is a hyperplane when $dimH=n-1$. If we've got $\space a_1,a_2,...,a_n\in{\mathbb{R}}$ **which are not all of them null**.
We have to prove that $H=${$(x_1,...,x_n)\in{\mathbb{R^n}}|a_1x_1+...+a_nx_n=0$} is an hyperplane of $\mathbb{R^n}$.

---

What I understand is that what we have to prove is that the dimension of $H$ is $n-1$. As I know that $H$ is a subspace of $V$ and the dimension of $V$ is n, we know that $dimH\le{n}$. And know, I suppose that I would have to deduce something else owing to the fact that $\space a_1,a_2,...,a_n\in{\mathbb{R}}$ are not all of them null. But I don't know which information to take from there...

Comment: Perhaps try viewing $H$ as the kernel of a certain linear functional?

Comment: What? I don't understand what you've said

Comment: Do you know what a linear transformation is ?

Comment: Yes, but this exercise is of the first unit we've given. I mean, the name of the unit is vectorial spaces... the kernel and the image and those things we gave on the second unit... so I don't think that I have to use that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know what the rank-nullity theorem is or don't want to use kernels or linear maps.

Let $ H = \{(x_1,x_2,...,x_n) \in V : a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + ...a_nx_n = 0.\}$ where at least one of the $a_i$'s is non zero WLOG consider $a_1 \neq 0$ then the equation defining $H$ can be rewritten as 
$$ x_1 = \frac{-1}{a_1}\sum_{k=2}^na_ix_i.$$

Therefore $\forall (x_1,...,x_n) \in H$:

\begin{align*}
(x_1,x_2,...,x_n) &= \left(\frac{-1}{a_1}\sum_{k=2}^na_ix_i ,\; x_2\,...,x_n \right) \\
&= x_2(-a_2/a_1,1,0,...,0) + x_3(-a_3/a_1,0,1,0,...,0) + ... + x_n(-a_n/a_1,0,...,0,1).\\  
\end{align*}

This means $H$ is generated by the vectors $\frac{-a_i}{a_1}e_1 + e_i$ for  $i = 2,3,...n.$ Since these vectors are also a linearly independent they form a basis of $H$ with $n-1$ elements. Therefore $\dim H = n-1.$